# How To Catch Any Error In Access VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, error-logging, microsoft-access-2013

I found a tutorial which showed me how to log errors in Access VBA, and it works mostly...but when checking my error table there are roughly 40 entries that do not have an error number logged nor is there a description.  I am wanting the error to not be displayed to the user, but when the error occurs email me the username, computername, error number and description so I can update as need be.  But w/o a description and/or error number I can't do much.

This is the procedure that I have, what do I need to add/alter/edit/update in order to be able to capture the missing errors?

```
Public Sub Error()
  On Error GoTo errorerrorhandler
  strDescription = Chr(34) & Err.Description & Chr(34)
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblErrorLog (ErrDate, CompName, UsrName, ErrNumber, ErrDescription, ErrModule)" _
  & " VALUES(#" & Now() & "#, '" & Environ("computername") _
  & "', '" & CurrentUser & "', " & Err.Number _
  & ", " & strDescription & ", '" & VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule & "')"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  Exit Sub

  errorerrorhandler:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And the above procedure displays error numbers in my table

```
6, 2113, 3070
```

**EDIT**
I am using the sub as an overall catch-all to try to write errors and I can remedy them once I am notified.  For example, this is a sub that I use to lookup data from a database and populate fields on a form:

```
Private Sub PullDataFromDB()
  On Error GoTo errHandler
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [ASD], [ID], [JN], [SP], [CI], [CM] FROM DBTable1 WHERE [IN] = CSTR(" & Me.[INNum] & ") ")
  Me.[INNum] = rs![ID]
  Me.[SD] = rs![ASD]
  Me.[JN] = rs![JN]
  Me.[SP] = rs![SP]
  Me.[CI] = rs![CI]
  Me.[CM] = rs![CM]
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Exit Sub

  errHandler:
  Error

End Sub
```

Comment: Why the vote to close?  @ Least leave me a comment so I know what is not on par?

Comment: Missing errors? I'd suggest at looking at the API for VBa. As it is it looks like you are mostly asking someone to just do your coding. What specifically are you stuck on? If you are asking for "give me every error there is in the book", then I don't think you'll get it like this.

Comment: This question is better suited for StackOverflow. Add information on how your sub is called. Calling it `Error()` like the inbuilt `Error()` function is not a good idea.

Comment: @Andre - edited ? to show how I call my Error procedure.  It is called from any sub when an error is hit as the errHandler

Comment: @ejbytes - not asking for code to be written for me.  Just wasn't sure if my method was missing anything that would encompass additional errors.  Thank you for the info to check the API's.